# Limit attempts for username and password using a loop

Tags: python

I am needing help creating a loop where a user only has three attempts to enter their username and password. For my assignment I have to create a separate text file with usernames and passwords that users can enter to access my POS system.

```
def verifyUIandPW(userID, password):
    
    passReturned = UIPassDict.get(userID)
    if (passReturned == password):
        return True

continueProgram = True

while(continueProgram):
    getAllUIAndPasswordData()

    UIPassDict.items()

    print("Welcome to the POS System\n\n")
    userID = ""
    password = ""
    UIandPWcounts = 0
    
    while userID != userID and password != password and UIandPWcounts < 3:
        userID = input("Please enter your user ID: ")
        password = input("Please enter your password: ")
        if (verifyUIandPW(userID, password)):
            print("Welcome, " + userID)
        else:
            print("Your account have been locked. Please contact system admin.") 
            UIandPWcounts +=1
```

Comment: What's your question? See [ask]

Comment: I am needing help creating a loop where a user only has three attemps to enter thier username and password. For my assingment I have to create a sepreate text file with usernames and passwords that users can enter to access my POS system.

Comment: but this is, in itself, a simple task. maybe you could edit and describe what issues you are facing?

Comment: How do you know your code isn't working? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.